# Приложение убирает фокус

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser

Написал небольшого бота, который переходит по ссылкам. Добавил возможность сворачивать в трей, дабы не мешалось. Так вот, когда приложение находится в трее и совершает клик, то с других окон снимается фокус, это доставляет дискомфорт. Сижу, например, в браузере, что-то печатаю, и тут бах - с браузера снимается фокус и нужно заново нажимать на текстовое поле. Если просто свернуть приложение, то такого не происходит. Есть ли способ избавиться от этого?

Клик осуществляется так: `element.InvokeMember("Click");`

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13052693/5045688).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Благодарю, этот способ работает. На каждый клик сделал `Enabled = false;` а при событии `DocumentCompleted`, обратно `Enabled = true;`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Тогда имеет смысл написать ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebBrowser` действительно может похищать фокус, когда URL загружается.

Для предотвращения этого, перез загрузкой следует устанавливать свойство `Enabled` родительского для браузера контрола в значение `false;`. А после её завершения, в событии `DocumentCompleted`, обратно устанавливать в значение `true`.